# How can I make my while scanf loop terminate when 0 is entered?

Tags: c, recursion, scanf

How can I make the following loop terminate when 0 (preceded and followed by a space) is entered? Right now I need to manually type '\n' to end the loop.

```
while (scanf("%hd", &array[length++]) == 1)
```

Comment: Compare the scanned value to `0`....

Comment: IMO your line is doing way too much stuff (it's scanfing, it's changing `length`, it's assigning to array element, it's validating the result of io)... simplify :)

Comment: pattmax " when 0 (preceded and followed by a space)" --> Do you need to detect `" 0 \n"` or can `" 0\n"` and `"0\n"` stop the loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanf into a temporary

```
short shorttmp;
while (scanf("%hd", &shorttmp) == 1) {
    if (shorttmp == 0) break;
    array[length++] = shorttmp;
    // ...
}
```